# $k$-modules and $A$-modules projective

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra and $U$ an $A$-module. $k$ is a commutative ring.

If $U$ is a projective $A$-module, is it a projective $k$-module ($A$ is not necessarily finitely-generated as a $k$-mod)

If $U$ is a projective $k$-module, is it a projective $A$-module. I think it is as $A\otimes_k U$ is a direct summand of $A\otimes_k k^n$, but not sure...

I tried thinking of it using change of ring functor ($k \to A$), but don't have enough theorems to support it. Like does the functor preserve projectives? Also, the second question seems unsuitable to be thought of with change of rings?

Thank you!

Comment: No. Take $U = A$ and take $A$ to be some $k$-algebra which isn’t projective as a $k$-module. The restriction functor does not preserve projectives.

Comment: Hi Qiaochu, thanks. That makes sense. What about the second question?

Comment: Also no. Take $k$ to be a field and take $U$ to have torsion, e.g. $A = k[x], U = k[x]/(x)$.

Comment: What is true is that *extension* of scalars preserves projectives, e.g. because it preserves free modules and taking direct summands.

Comment: Hi Qiaochu! Thank you. if this doesn't hold, then I cannot explain the following question anymore. Would you be so kind to take a look?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828200/relative-projective-and-projective-coincide